rest_forbidden Sorry you are not allowed to do that
I am JWT authenticating using a custom endpoint through the JWT token, and I have set this endpoint as '/wp-json/jwt-auth/v1/token?username=username&password=password'. The token is generated easily. However, when I set a second custom endpoint to handle it, and I set the Bearer token, I am getting the following error:

{ "code": "rest_forbidden", "message": "Sorry, you are not allowed to do that.", "data": { "status": 401 } }

I am using the 'JWT Authentication for WP REST API' plugin. I have created a custom plugin in PHP, and in this custom plugin, I have used a permission callback in register_rest_route. I just need a solution for this
public function wsr_rest_api_init()
    {
        register_rest_route(
            'wp-secure-rest-api/v1', 'posts',
            array(
                'methods' => 'GET',
                'callback' => [$this,'wsr_get_posts'],
                'permission_callback'=>function(){

                }
            )
        );
    }
    public function wsr_get_posts(){
        $args = array(
            'post_type' => 'post',
            'posts_per_page' => 5,
            'orderby' => 'date',
            'order' => 'DESC'
        );
        $query=new WP_Query($args);
        $posts = array();

        if ($query->have_posts()) {
            while ($query->have_posts()) {
                $query->the_post();

                $posts[] = array(
                    'id' => get_the_ID(),
                    'title' => get_the_title(),
                    'link' => get_the_permalink(),
                    'excerpt' => get_the_excerpt(),
                    'date' => get_the_date(),
                );
            }
        }
        wp_reset_postdata();
        return $posts;
    }', 

and what can be corrected so that when I send the token, all my posts should be displayed in a json format and i am postman.

"and in this custom plugin, I have used a permission callback in register_rest_route" - you have only provided an "empty" function that doesn't return anything. It should return either a boolean value, or a WP_Error instance. https://developer.wordpress.org/rest-api/extending-the-rest-api/adding-custom-endpoints/#permissions-callback
